# TrueCrypt "silently" updated bootloader

Tags: truecrypt, boot

I have just updated TrueCrypt from version 7.1a to 7.2. Upon next system restart I have noticed that bootloader was updated as well, because it now shows message about TrueCrypt being not safe.

There was no information in version 7.2 installer about possible update to bootloader (only about updating Windows version of TrueCrypt). In certain BIOS configurations update to bootloader is considered a security risk and may be blocked by BIOS itself.

Shall I treat this as a security breach? Shall I be concerned in anyway?

Note that this is purely theoretical question, asking if any change to bootloader should be considered as a treat or as a normal situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a security breach. It is as fine as it was before. There is no change in safety.

7.2 was created in order to warn everyone that TrueCrypt will stop being developed and practically it is a limited version of TrueCrypt's final release: 7.1a.

You should have not updated to 7.2 because there is no reason to do so and no functionality improvement from 7.1a to 7.2.

At this moment, TC (7.1a) is perfectly safe, but considering the fast-paced development of computing power, on the long term you should consider switching to VeraCrypt which is safer against brute force.

Comment: "*considering the fast-paced development of computing power*" I wish that was still the case :(

Comment: I have accepted your question, but it doesn't directly answer my question. I wasn't asking, if TrueCrypt is OK in version 7.2 (I know, it is), but whether in general "silent" update of bootloader, without direct express of will on user side isn't theoretically speaking a security breach.

Comment: Plus: There is certainly at least one reason for installing 7.2. It adds "Decrypt Permanently" feature and menu item to "Volumes" menu. And it allow you to decrypt USB disks permanently on-the-fly. With 7.1a and earlier the only way to decrypt an USB disk was to copy its data somewhere, format it (plus some additional wipe-oriented procedures) and copy data back to formatted, unencrypted disk.

Comment: @trejder if the update is an official one, as in this case, no, it can't be considered a security breach even if the changes were not fully documented.